# Using $() in docker commands doesn't seem to work

Tags: linux, docker, unix

I want to stop all running docker containers with the command `sudo docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)`.  But when I run it, docker outputs

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/json?all=1: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
"docker stop" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker stop --help'.

Usage:  docker stop [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Stop one or more running containers
```

Just running `docker ps -a -q` outputs the Docker IDs, but when I combine it with a Docker command, it doesn't work.  Thank you.

Comment: Do you need `sudo` to run Docker commands?

Comment: Yeah, I left it out of the question, but I am indeed using sudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize that the sudo is required in the command substitution also:

```
sudo docker stop $(sudo docker ps -a -q)
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you trying to run `docker ps -a -q` and `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)` in two different consoles/users? The error shown is in fact two different errors:

1. `docker ps -q -a` cannot complete due to insufficient permissions
2. `docker stop ...` gets empty argument list due to error in subshell

Edit:
If using `sudo` each command is running in different shell/subshell which inherits privileges/environment. But the subshells are invoked in order from the outermost. So the script will be invoket in order `docker ps` and then `sudo docker stop`. The first one will not have privileges elevated.

Comment: I only have one console opened.  I am also running in sudo and still getting the permission error.

Comment: I just did $(docker ps -a -q) and am getting permission error.  I didn't realize I had to include sudo inside of $().  It works now.

Comment: If you are runing with `sudo` don't be surprised. Each command must be prepended `sudo` as the subshell gets invoked **before** the sudo privilege elevation.